# files wipedout/deleted in FTP server during power fluctuation

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ftp

> We have a FTP server which holds data upto 10MB - used for storing the
>   configuration files, which will be shared among all the Other Devices.
>   And on every boot all the Devices will download the configuration
>   files from FTP server and configure the Devices based on the data.
>
> On every boot up, our Device will identify the number of files and based
>   on the result, will download the configuration files.
>
> Once we observed that, the file counts were 0 in FTP server - and we
>   found that is there were Power Fluctuation happened on FTP server.
>
> So on the next time Device assumed that the FTP server has no files, so uploaded the new files.

Actual issue - why the data in FTP were wiped out/deleted? Kindly help me to find out the root cause of this issue.

**Logs**

```
2015-03-30 04:15:56,978 - In DownLoad: listACMFiles: No. of Files in FTP is: 9
2015-03-30 04:52:14,910 - In DownLoad: listACMFiles: No. of Files in FTP is: 9
2015-03-30 17:20:41,165 - In DownLoad: listACMFiles: No. of Files in FTP is: 9
2015-03-30 19:29:48,472 - In DownLoad: listACMFiles: Unable to Read the FTP 
2015-03-30 19:29:49,383 - In DownLoad: listACMFiles: No. of Files in FTP is: 0
2015-03-30 20:33:29,165 - In DownLoad: listACMFiles: No. of Files in FTP is: 9
```

**JAR used** - commons-net-1.4.1.jar

**Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FTPFileOpertaions {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FTPFileOpertaions.class);
    private int downloadFiles(FTPClient configDataFtp) {
        boolean result = false;
        FTPFile[] fileList = null;
        int noOfFiles = 0;
        logger.info("In DownLoad: Listing the files:");
        for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < 3; iLoop++) {
            try {
                fileList = configDataFtp.listFiles();
                noOfFiles = fileList.length;
                result = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("In DownLoad: listACMFiles: Unable to Read the FTP");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("In DownLoad: listACMFiles: Unable to Read the FTP");
            }

            if (result) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Return if the file list retrieval fails.     
        if(!result){
            return result;
        }

        logger.info("In DownLoad: listACMFiles: No. of Files in FTP is: "
                + noOfFiles);

        return noOfFiles;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me to find out the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Files just don't disappear.  If it was saved to disk, either something deleted it, or you have a bad/unreadable disk that may have been repaired upon reboot.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your reply. Yeah might be you are correct with the bad/unreachable sector in disk. But I just want to know that on the next iteration itself we got file count as "0". That is the Device didn't get that exception again - it is passed and came out of the for loop. So am just asking that the sectors got repaired between the iterations (like with in 500 milli seconds)...?

Comment: When you get the Unable to read the FTP, and return false, what does the caller do?  Do you still have a connection to the FTP Server?  It's really hard to say why that happened. could the caller be reconnecting and not setting the path correctly after the reconnect?  I don't see anything in that code that checks to see if you have a valid server connection.  I also don't see any differentiation in the Exception handling.  You might want different messages for IOException, FTPConnectionClosedException, and then any others with different messages.

Comment: Am not returning false, actually iterating whenever i got exception (totally thrice). And here, in the second iteration - am not getting the same exception and so that the "result" is true and breaking the loop.

Comment: Yes, I did wrong in the message handling. But my question is, when any exception was occurred, Consider the FTPConnectionClosedException during the second iteration - the error log message should added again.

Comment: Agreed, I would separate the messages just in case it happens again, and return the false to the caller in the exception handling, since the caller is who established the connection.

Comment: It could truly be an IOException on the line and the FTP server was going through some sort of recovery (rebuilding the cache).  I would look on the FTP server logs and see if anything shows up.

Comment: Yes, we also found that that could be an IOException. And as our FTP server has very low memory, we were not tracing any logs. That server is running on a small chip which holds the configuration files. Also there were no proper time log for the files. It was too difficult to corner the issue, posted here that if some one could have faced these kind of issue - we might get some sort of solution....